# How to update a FormControl inside of FormArray in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I can update a FormControl inside of FormGroup like this:

```
form.setControl('happyControl',
   new FormControl('happy value', Validators.required)
);
```

But inside of a FormArray, I can't edit picked FormControl.

In myForm controls > FormArray > FormGroup, I can't set the control. My code is like this:

```
let firstFormGroup = form.controls.myFormArrayControl.controls;

firstFormGroup[0].setControl('happyControl', 
    new FormControl('sad value', Validators.minlength(2))
);
```

How can I access and update the control?

Comment: Does is work when you try to update the control at a specific index, like this: `firstFormGroup[0].setControl('happyControl'...` ?

Comment: @R.Richards I tried like you write, I can see the value in FormGroup object but view is not updating. I can't understand. I am trying to solve this for 3 days...

Answer (score 0):

You must call `updateValueAndValidity()`.

I think like that, but it would help if you publish the complete code:

```
firstFormGroup[0].updateValueAndValidity()
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but It's not worked. When I use setValidators and after updateValueAndValidity method, It worked. 

Here is plunkr link (I don't know why it's not working :) http://plnkr.co/edit/XVNhljhiK2LYlKqNsAfc

Comment: Yes you must set the value before to call `updateValueAndValidity`.

Comment: If you check the link you can see that I already set it in the line of 116. If I had another mistake, please fork it or tell me what can I do to fix this.